# My "C" thread function and signal handler combined together fails to handle the LINUX SIGIO signal the second time it is invoked

Tags: c, linux

Good afternoon, Here is my "C" thread function and signal handler combined together to handle the LINUX SIGIO signal. The problem I am encountering is that the first time I run my test program this function handles and recognizes the SIGIO signal correctly. However, on subsequent time(2,3,4...) this function fails to recognize the SIGIO properly.
   My hypothesis is that this behavior has something to do with the life cycle of the /proc//fdinfo/1" file. Please let me about the details of the life cycle of the /proc//fdinfo/1" file and whether my hypothesis is correct. Thank you very much.

```
void *reader(int signal)
{
    pid_t pid1,pid2;
    int status;
    int fd[2];
    char buf[256];
    char buffer[256];
    char filename[256];
    int myfd;
    int length;
    struct rusage usage;

    printf("SIGNAL = %d\n",signal);

    length = 256;
    if (signal == 0){
        return NULL;
    }

    pipe(fd);
    if ((pid1 = fork())) {
                sprintf(filename,"/proc/%d/fdinfo/1",pid1);
//              printf("UNLINK = %d\n",unlink(filename));
                myfd = open(filename,O_RDONLY);
                if (myfd == -1){
                        printf("myfd = %d filename = %s\n",myfd,filename);
                        printf("errno = %d\n",errno);
                }
                int myretval = mmap(NULL,
                                    length,
                                    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                    MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED,
                                    myfd,
                                    0);
                printf("myretval = %d\n",myretval);
                fcntl(0,F_SETFL,F_SETOWN);
                fcntl(1,F_SETFL,F_SETOWN);
                       fcntl(2,F_SETFL,F_SETOWN);
                fcntl(3,F_SETFL,F_SETOWN);
                if (signal == SIGIO){
                        printf("SIGNAL SIGIO RECEIVED");
                }
                close(fd[WRITE]);
                FILE *read = fdopen(fd[READ],"r");
                while (!feof(read)) {
                        fgets(buf,256,read);
                //      printf("child says: %s",buf);   
                }
                pid2 = wait3(&status,0, &usage);
   }
   else {
                close(fd[READ]);
                close(fileno(stdout));
                dup(fd[WRITE]);
                //  child only unblock mask

                fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                fcntl(1, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                fcntl(2, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
                printf("WE ARE HERE\n");
                execl("/h/fchang03/five","five",NULL);

  }

}
```

Comment: You didn't show us the code responsible for the arranging to catch the signal. Since that's what's failing, that's probably where the bug is.